# How to call a method after bean initialization is complete?

Tags: spring, initialization, startup, applicationcontext

I have a use case where I need to call a (non-static) method in the bean only-once at the ApplicationContext load up. Is it ok, if I use MethodInvokingFactoryBean for this? Or we have a some better solution?

As a side note, I use ConfigContextLoaderListener to load the Application Context in web application. And want, that if bean 'A' is instantiated just call methodA() once.

How can this be done nicely?

Answer (score 209, accepted):

You can use something like:

```xml
<beans>
    <bean id="myBean" class="..." init-method="init"/>
</beans>
```

This will call the "init" method when the bean is instantiated.

Comment: postConstruct should be better in most cases, though, as we dont wanna mess up with spring bean initialization.

Comment: @lwpro2 What do you mean by "don't wanna mess up with spring bean initialization" here?

Answer (score 352):

To expand on the `@PostConstruct` suggestion in other answers, this really is the best solution, in my opinion.

- It keeps your code decoupled from the Spring API (`@PostConstruct` is in `javax.*`)
- It explicitly annotates your init method as something that needs to be called to initialize the bean
- You don't need to remember to add the init-method attribute to your spring bean definition, spring will automatically call the method (assuming you register the annotation-config option somewhere else in the context, anyway).

Comment: Thanks, this works. Note if you want to use with Spring you must include "<context:annotation-config />" to register the CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bean (as mentioned above)

Comment: A suitable `<context:component-scan>` also works, and can be useful for reducing startup time if you have large non-Spring libraries on your classpath.

Comment: The JavaDoc for PostConstruct says that only one method can be annotated with it per class:http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html

Comment: @PostConstruct doesn't work with a transactional manager, see: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/50069-no-transaction-in-transactional-service-called-from-postconstruct/page3

Comment: @PostConstruct also won't be of much use to you when the bean you are instantiating is not a class of your own but some third party class

Answer (score 114):

There are three different approaches to consider, as described in the [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-lifecycle)

## Use init-method attribute

#### Pros:

- Does not require bean to implement an interface.

#### Cons:

- No immediate indication in source code that this method is required after construction to ensure the bean is correctly configured.

---

## Implement InitializingBean

#### Pros:

- No need to specify init-method, or turn on component scanning / annotation processing.
- Appropriate for beans supplied with a library, where we don't want the application using this library to concern itself with bean lifecycle.

#### Cons:

- More invasive than the init-method approach.

---

## Use JSR-250 [@PostConstruct](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations) lifecyle annotation

#### Pros:

- Useful when using component scanning to autodetect beans.
- Makes it clearer that a specific method is to be used for initialisation. Intent is closer to the code.

#### Cons:

- Initialisation no longer centrally specified in configuration.
- You must remember to turn on annotation processing (which can sometimes be forgotten)

Comment: I think it's actually a good thing to use `@PostConstruct` precisely because it is part of the class that it needs the method calling at the end of initialization processing.

Comment: If that class REALLY needs it and you cannot do it in constructor, than I consider it to be code smell.

Answer (score 42):

Have you tried implementing [`InitializingBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html)? It sounds like exactly what you're after.

The downside is that your bean becomes Spring-aware, but in most applications that's not so bad.

Comment: Is there a reason you would choose implementing the interface over specifying an init-method in the XML?

Comment: Thats a matter of taste. The interface is part of the Spring component model and serves that and only that purpose while for a custom named method it might not really be obvious that it has to be called to complete component lifecycle. So this serves communication mainly. Of course with the drawback of the introduced dependency to the Spring framework. A nice way in between is the usage of @PostConstruct, as it has clear semantics but does not introduce the dependency...

Comment: Oliver gives me some nice excuses, but really I'd just forgotten about the init-method :) One other reason is that the type itself knows that it needs to be "finished" after all the properties have been set - it isn't fundamentally something which *should* be in the configuration.

Answer (score 8):

You could deploy a custom [BeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp) in your application context to do it. Or if you don't mind implementing a Spring interface in your bean, you could use the [InitializingBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-initializingbean) interface or the "init-method" directive (same link).

Comment: Does anyone has details on how to write a BeanPostProcessor. That sounds to be exactly what I need.

Cheers :)

Comment: Spring ships with many examples. Just look at the JavaDoc API for BeanPostProcessor and you'll find links to many implementing classes. Then look at the source code for them.

Answer (score -9):

To further clear any confusion about the two approach i.e use of

1. `@PostConstruct` and
2. `init-method="init"`

From personal experience, I realized that using (1) only works in a servlet container, while (2) works in any environment, even in desktop applications. So, if you would be using Spring in a standalone application, you would have to use (2) to carry out that "call this method after initialization.

Comment: Technically, `@PostConstruct` (when used in a Spring-based app) is tied to the lifespan of the owning Spring context. Such contexts can be used in all sorts of applications.

Comment: That was the behaviour i was expecting but didn't work for me.