# What is the main method of a WAR file?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Recently, I've reapackaged my java spring application to become a WAR file for deployment in tomcat. After some testing I noticed, that `public static void main(String[] args)` is not executed. Some necessary initialization of my application is done in `main`. Is there something like a `main` method in a WAR file? What is the appropiate place in a WAR file to run some initialization?

Comment: You can specify in the `web.xml` file to execute a class on startup...

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686507/how-to-add-a-hook-to-the-application-context-initialization-event

Comment: This looks specific to Spring Boot - please update the tags, both answers posted at the moment don't take this fact into account.

Comment: After spending 2 days on trying different solutions I realized the main issue is that main function is not executed in war file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found another way, that is independent of spring and tomcat: The `@PostConstruct` annotation. In code:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // initialization code goes here
}
```

This method gets executed whether I run my application standalone or in tomcat.

For more information see [How to call a method after bean initialization is complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088550/spring-how-to-call-a-method-after-bean-initialization-is-complete)
or [Init method in Spring Controller (annotation version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419695/init-method-in-spring-controller-annotation-version?lq=1)

Answer (score 11):

You can add a listener to your `web.xml` file:

```
<listener>
    <description>Application startup and shutdown events</description>
    <display-name>Test</display-name>
    <listener-class>com.package.package.StartClass</listener-class>
</listener>

public class StartClass implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
         //Context destroyed code here
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent)
    {
        //Context initialized code here
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to change the  `display-name` :-)

Comment: @AaronDigulla you mean he may want to change the display name lol this is just an example...

Comment: I don't have a web.xml file, but do that with SpringBootServletInitializer.

Comment: @user1785730: Annotate your class with `@WebListener`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html

Comment: I work on a project, where web.xml has three listeners, and all of them do not belong to the project files  - they are about some Spring classes. So, it is not a listener that points to the start class.

Answer (score 4):

Well, You will have to create a listener in your web.xml that will be invoked by container at the time of startup.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.rdv.example.WebAppContext</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And this class will be implementing `ServletContextListener`

```
public class WebAppContext implements ServletContextListener {

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
// Do your processing that you are trying to do in main method.
}
```