# Spring session bean: initialize with values

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I've a doubt about Spring session bean. Let me try to explain what I need and what I did. I need to store on a session variable (in that case a Bean) the user_id so, when I need to create some record on db I can keep track of who did what.

To do that, for first, I created a bean and, second, I modified my application context in that way:

```
<bean id="UserInfo" class="net.agdev.session.UserInfo" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

I read that using this :

```
ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext().getBean("UserInfo");
```

is ppossible to access to the bean, but it's not yet clear how to fill that bean..

I tryed to read on Spring documentation how to initalize the bean and how to recall on my Class controller but I didn't find anything.

Could you suggest where to find an example or a tutorial to do that?

many thanks!

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean how to get the user_id into the session bean? Depending on your application this should probably happen right after the user "logged in". Meaning, if you for instance have a login webflow or controller, set the user_id in your session bean within that webflow or controller.

So if I understood your context correctly this has only very little to do with Spring itself and mostly with your application :-)

If you want other aspects of your bean initialized for instance from operations on other services you could set an init-method on the bean definition as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088550/spring-how-to-call-a-method-after-bean-initialization-is-complete/1088584#1088584).

Comment: I found that very helpful link http://claymitchell.net/2008/02/11/spring-framework-annotation-sessionattribute-can-be-confusing/ and I solved using HttpSession object. Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

By aspect programming like `AspectJ`. You have to set some trigger, for example after an user does something you have to read your bean and fill it the operation info that have been performed by the user.

You can use `@annotation` to define trigger or you can do it by spring xml file. I think you have to use an application context bean and not a session bean.