# Clear GUI forms when created through spring as a singleton bean

Tags: java, spring, user-interface

In a desktop application created using java and spring, the GUI forms are created as singleton beans and therefore whenever a form is displayed, all the preveously entered values are there. Is there a better way to get a fresh form than clearing each form field through java code? Thanks in advance

Comment: is it common practice to use singleton beans in GUI apps? And, is it common to use springframework to create GUI apps? It seems sort of surprising to me, because GUI & spring doesn't seem like a good fit. But perhaps what you want is to use prototype scope beans rather than the default singleton scope.

Comment: Is there a reason you chose singleton scope for this form object?

Comment: This is an half way developed application that I have to work with. Is there any better way to implement the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I override the `dispose` method and called `init` method after `super.dispose()`, in the `init` method, added the following line at the begining: `getContentPane().removeAll();`. 
It works well for my requirement, when I want the data to remain in the form, I simply hide the form and when I want a fresh form, I dispose the form and show the form again.

Answer (score 2):

You could force a new singleton to be instantiated like this

```
public class MyForm {
    // The instance
    private static MyForm instance = new MyForm();
    // Private constructor prevents instantiation from other classes
    private MyForm() { }
    // Get the singleton
    public static MyForm getInstance() { return instance; }

    // Force a new instance to be created         
    public static void resetInstance() {
           instance = new MyForm();
    }
}
```

But this is not really singleton behaviour anymore and maybe you should just use a new instantiated class. Something like:

```
myPanel.removeAll();
myPanel.add(new MyForm());
```

(the constructor should become public of course)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your second sugession.

Comment: I think I found a better solution, but not sure whether it is the correct way. I override the `dispose` method and called `init` method after `super.dispose()`, in the `init` method, added the following line at the begining: `getContentPane().removeAll();`. It works well for my requirement, when I want the data to remain in the form, I simply hide the form and when I want a fresh form, I dispose the form and show the form again. If you find any faults in this method, please comment.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a simpler alternative, please use singleton=false. If you want to retain some of the initialization snippets, then use init method or bean post processors.

Comment: Could you please explain the usage of init method and bean post processors?

Comment: This is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088550/spring-how-to-call-a-method-after-bean-initialization-is-complete