# What is the correct way to register a shutdown hook in Spring 3?

Tags: spring, neo4j

A tutorial on [how to embed Neo4j in a java application](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-setup.html) recommends registering a shutdown hook like so:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( new Thread() {
    // do shutdown work here
});
```

I'm wondering where the best place to put this code - or in fact any code that needs to run once when Spring starts. Is it simply a case of [registering a bean with an init method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088550/spring-how-to-call-a-method-after-bean-initialization-is-complete) and putting the code in that?

I'd be interested to know this and more specifically how others have registered a shutdown hook when using an embedded Neo4j in their Spring application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just declare your bean for the graphdatabase-service with the correct `destroy-method`:

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase"
        destroy-method="shutdown">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="data/testdb.db"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <map>
            <entry key="allow_store_upgrade" value="true"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Have you got an annotation configuration equivalent of this?

Comment: @Bean public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() { return new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(storeDir, config); }

Comment: @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown") public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() { return new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(storeDir, config); }

Comment: I found that this might not work in the case of a ctrl+c being issued. That is, the destroy-method isn't called. If you need it to be, you can create a bean that implements `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware` and in the implemented method, do `((ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext).registerShutdownHook();` which will get your context shutdown called when the runtime exits. Under the covers Spring probably calls the Runtime method you mentioned.

Answer (score -3):

Using 1.8.1 Neo4j, and SDN 2.1 - the above does not work for my Eclipse/Jetty environment.

Nearly every time I start / stop with Eclipse "server" controls, I see this on startup:

INFO: Non clean shutdown detected on log ...

NOTE: I do not set the "allow-store-upgrade" property though. I thought that had nothing to do with clean shutdown?