# Beans creation faild in spring

Tags: java, spring

I have an interface like this

```
public interface InterfaceA {
    public String methodA();
}
```

and I have implemented it like this

```
public class ClassA implements InterfaceA {

    @Override
    public String methodA(){
       return "HELLO";
    }
}
```

I'm trying to reference a bean of this class in another class

```
public class ClassB {

   @Autowired
   private InterfaceA mybean;

   String str = mybean.methodA();
}
```

I have the following bean configuration 
    `<bean id="mybean" class="ClassA"></bean>`

Most interesting point is if I remove all the declaration and implementation of the `methodA` in `InterfaceA` and `ClassA` and then try to just this

```
public class ClassB {

    @Autowired
    private InterfaceA mybean;

}
```

no error is shown.
In the other case the following error is shown when I try to run this application: *"No qualifying bean of type [ClassA] found for dependency"*

Comment: So what is the actual question?

Comment: can you post the complete stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the livecyle of a bean and a java class!

in your `ClassB` you have two variables. `mybean` will been populated by Spring after the object instance ins created (by spring). But `String str = mybean.methodA();` will be assinged as soon as the object instance is created. And at this point the variable `mybean` is still null, and therfor the instance creation will fail!

Solution: use `@PostConstruct`, spring init-method, or implement [`InitializingBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) -- see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1089691/280244) for an overview

```
public class ClassB {

   @Autowired
   private InterfaceA mybean;

   private String str;

   void afterPropertiesSet() {
      String str = mybean.methodA();
   }
}
```