# How to inject ApplicationContext from Component?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to use ApplicationContext instance inside MyComponent class. When I try to autowire, I am getting null pointer exception when Spring initializing my components on startup.

Is there any way to autowire ApplicationContext inside MyComponent class?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    MyComponent myComponent;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;  //Spring autowires perfectly at this level

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
    }

}


@Component
public class MyComponent{

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ctx;

    public MyComponent(){
        ctx.getBean(...) //throws null pointer
    }

}
```

Comment: You can simply implement the interface `ApplicationContextAware` to retrieve a reference to the application context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get bean using application context in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088780/how-to-get-bean-using-application-context-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom ItemReader with spring-data-jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37224141/custom-itemreader-with-spring-data-jpa)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to make sure, that your dependency (bean) is initialized and ready in the constructor you should use constructor injection, not field injection:

```
    @Autowired
    public MyComponent(ApplicationContext ctx){
        ctx.getBean(...) // do something
    }
```

Another approach is to use [`@PostConstruct`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) like below:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ctx;

    public MyComponent(){

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ctx.getBean(...); // do something
    }

}
```

You get `NPE` because spring needs to first create the bean (`MyComponent`) and then set the field's value, so in the constructor, the value of your field is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `MyComponent` constructor is called before Spring autowires `ApplicationContext`.
Here are two ways:

• Inject the dependency in constructor ([better way](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/field-dependency-injection-considered-harmful/)):

```java
@Component
public class MyComponent{
    private final ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Autowired
    public MyComponent(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        ctx.getBean(...);
    }
}
```

• Or inject it via field injection (worse way) and use `@PostConstruct` lifecycle annotation:

```java
@Component
public class MyComponent {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx; // not final

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        ctx.getBean(...);
    }
}
```

It may be less safe, but it provides more readable code, I think.

---

Oh, and there's the way I personally use, with [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/).
It makes there's almost no boilerplate code until you really need to do some actions at construction time or have some non-autowireable fields. :D

```java
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = @Autowired)
public class MyComponent {
    private final ApplicationContext ctx;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        ctx.getBean(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I was 19 minutes too slow. ':D

Comment: For some reason constructor injection not working in @Component. I'm getting BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [pkg.MyBean]  No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException