# How can I run jobs after spring beans is initialized?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, autowired

I am working on Spring 4 mvc and hibernate 
I want to run code on the server startup that will use the get data from the database then do some business logic

where can I put my code I tried to put the code

```
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.onStartup(ServletContext)
```

but I was not able to use @Autowired variables

```
          public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

        @Autowired
        TaskDAO task;
        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            return new Class[] { SpringRootConfig.class };
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            return new Class[] { SpringWebConfig.class };
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            return new String[] { "/" };
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
            task.getAllTasks()
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onStartup(servletContext);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not able to autowire variables because your class is not managed by spring. So annotate your class with `@Component` annotation.

Then you can define a method that will do your logic (for example *onStartup* method) and annotate it with the `@PostConstruct` annotation as explained in this answers.

[How to call a method after bean initialization is complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088550/how-to-call-a-method-after-bean-initialization-is-complete)

It will execute the method after the beans initialization.

This could be your class:

```
    @Component
    public class WebInitializer{
      @Autowire
      TaskDAO task;

      @PostConstruct
      private void onStartup(){
          task.getAllTasks();
          // Do whatever you want
    }
}
```