# Set common variable in Spring Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I have a Java Spring Configuration class like this. I want to set a variable that several of my beans depend on, turn it into a bean, and use it as a dependency. How can I make the `setVariable()` method happen first? I'm converting my code from Guice, where this variable was being set in the overridden 'Configuration' method. Does Spring have something like that?

```
@Configuration
class SpringConfiguration{
    String variable;

    public void setVariable(){
        variable = System.getenv("whatever")
    }

    @Bean
public void variable(){
    return variable;
}

    @Bean
    public void myService(){
        return new MyService(variable);
    }

    @Bean
    public void myService2(){
        return new MyService2(variable);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a method after bean initialization is complete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088550/how-to-call-a-method-after-bean-initialization-is-complete)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
@Configuration
class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean(name="variable")
    public String geVariable() {
        return System.getenv("whatever");
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("variable")
    public MyService getMyService() {
        return new MyService(geVariable());
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("variable")
    public MyService2 getMyService2() {
        return new MyService2(geVariable());
    }
}
```

Like that you can insure that `variable` will be initialized before `service1` and `service2`, note that `DependsOn` in this case is just for clarification purposes.